# Bind datepicker to value inside array

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have an array which consists of an date value and time array. I am trying to bind my date value inside the array to a datepicker. I tried looping through my array and binding with v-model the date value inside it to my datepicker. But I am getting the following error:

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at VueComponent.tableYear (VDatePicker.ts?9174:192)
    at Watcher.get (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4479)
    at Watcher.evaluate (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4584)
    at VueComponent.computedGetter [as tableYear] (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4836)
    at VueComponent.genTableHeader (VDatePicker.ts?9174:398)
    at VueComponent.genPickerBody (VDatePicker.ts?9174:486)
    at VueComponent.genPicker (index.ts?99ca:56)
    at Proxy.render (VDatePicker.ts?9174:514)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3548)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4066)
logError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888
globalHandleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1879
handleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1839
Vue._render @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3550
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4066
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4479
run @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4554
flushSchedulerQueue @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4310
eval @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1980
flushCallbacks @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1906
Promise.then (async)
timerFunc @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1933
nextTick @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1990
queueWatcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4402
update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4544
notify @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:730
reactiveSetter @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1055
proxySetter @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4631
listeners.click @ index.ts?f50b:118
listeners.click @ index.ts?78b8:268
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854
invoker @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2179
original._wrapper @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6917
```

Could someone look at it and tell me where my mistake is?
here is my code where I bind it to my datepicker:

```
 <v-menu v-for="(item, index) in dates"
        ref="menu"
        v-model="menu"
        :close-on-content-click="false"
        :return-value.sync="item.date"
        transition="scale-transition"
        offset-y
        min-width="auto"
      >
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }" >
          <v-text-field
            v-model="item.date"
            label="Picker in menu"
            prepend-icon="mdi-calendar"
            readonly
            v-bind="attrs"
            v-on="on"
          ></v-text-field>
        </template>
        <v-date-picker
          v-model="date"
          no-title
          scrollable
        >
```

here is my js:

```
 data: () => ({
    selectedTime: [],

    dates: [{date : new Date().toISOString().substr(0,10), time: []}],
    menu: false,
    modal: false,
    menu2: false,
  }),

  methods:{
      addTimeFields(){

        this.selectedTime.push({
          startTime:"",
          endTime: "",
        })
        this.dates[0].time.push([
        this.selectedTime
          ])
        console.log(this.dates[0].time)



      }
  }
```

Comment: it should be `v-model="item.date"` in `<v-date-picker>`

Comment: thanks this did the magic. Could you explain me why this approach worked? I am new to vue so i would like to learn from my mistake